# extension not remove via composer

Tags: magento2, composer

i have disable extension after i can remove extension via composer like this way

```
php bin/magento module:disable <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> --clear-static-content
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
composer remove VendorName/VendorExtensionRepository
```

but still not working for me 
**also i have correct credential add but still below error showing**

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   Invalid credentials for
>   'https://repo.wyomind.com/packages.json', aborting.

[image]

Comment: check credentials

Comment: my credentials is correct..

Comment: which specific module you have? if it's installed using composer, you can remove it using uninstall.

Comment: but it seems an authentication issue

Comment: yes this extension install previous developer via composer and i can removed it

Comment: Try to uninstall extension `php bin/magento module:uninstall Namespace_Modulename` and check have you get same error?

Comment: @ChiragPatel still not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is not a module. the problem is that you've added this repository and composer checks which modules are available on this repository, but this check requires you to provide correct credentials.

check your projects composer.json for something like `{ "type": "composer", "url": "'https://repo.wyomind.com/" },` and remove it.

But keep in mind, that you are no longer able to install modules from this repository.

Comment: did you add this repository globaly? check `~/.composer/auth.json` and remove it from there too

Comment: i have above repository in composer.json and again run remove command

Comment: you have to delete the repository. as I said: composer wants to check the repository for packages and this requires you authentication. If you don't want composer to do this, you have to remove the repository everywhere you've added it

Comment: means i have not install this extension my previous developer installed it i have only remove in root directory composer.json file

Comment: removing the extension is not enough. you have to remove the repository

Answer (score 0):

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.wyomind.com/packages.json', aborting.

The error above sometimes occurs during authentication when you are trying to input your public and private key directly on the CLI rather than putting it in `auth.json` file.

Like below `auth.json` file pattern

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username":"<your public key>",
            "password":"<your private key>"
        }
    }
}
```

And use [Magento Uninstall Modules](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html#instgde-cli-uninst-mod-uninst) way instead to uninstall a module:

```
magento module:uninstall [--backup-code] [--backup-media] [--backup-db] [-r|--remove-data] [-c|--clear-static-content] \
{ModuleName} ... {ModuleName}
```

Example:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Vendor>_<Module>
```

-r flag removes module data. Then run afterward the upgrade:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but i know this all things but still not working for me